# SMTP login only works via AUTH PLAIN

Tags: phpmailer, telnet

This is my first time using telnet; I'm using it to debug PHPMailer. Here's what I get when logged in:

```
EHLO localserver.com
250-mx.zohomail.com Hello localserver.com (162.243.32.109 (162.243.32.109))
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250 SIZE 53477376
```

Following [this tutorial](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/01/using-telnet-with-an-smtp-server/), I try logging in via AUTH LOGIN.

When I give my password, it fails.

However, if I AUTH PLAIN, it works.

PHPMailer (I'm using the [basic template](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) provided at their git page with debugging set to 4) debugging shows me that they are using AUTH LOGIN.

So it seems that there are two ways to solve my problem.

-figure out why AUTH LOGIN doesn't work

-figure out how to get PHPMailer to use AUTH PLAIN.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the authentication type with the `AuthType` property. Just set it to `PLAIN`.

You don't need to use SMTPDebug = 4; 2 should be enough for this.

Comment: I messed around with this; being an amateur, I added $->authtype=PLAIN; (below $mail ->Host), which did nothing. I had a hard time finding examples via google, too. Thanks for the debug tip (4 helped me realize that the problem might be authtype; 3 didn't show enough info for that).

Comment: PHP is case sensitive for vars and property names. Use *exactly* what I said and it should work. It's all in the docs too.

Comment: For those total newbs like myself, it goes like this: $mail->AuthType = 'PLAIN';